# Selenium с использованием C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Хотел бы написать возможность парсинга данных в формы WinForms, с целью последующей их обработки.
При запуске в коде драйвера Selenium, запускается консоль (я так полагаю для логов). Возможно ли запускать без консоли? Либо чтобы эти логи выводились куда-нибудь еще?

Comment: так вам надо парсинг или селениум?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501623/chromedriver-console-application-hide

Comment: Селениум производить некие действия, параллельно собирая информацию в определенные структуры. Данные нужно в дальнейшем обработать.

Comment: Вопрос уже решен. Спасибо maxwell.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501623/chromedriver-console-application-hide

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без редактирования DriverService.cs

```
var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

а потом просто создаёшь, допустим, Firefox, используя эту переменную

```
IWebDriver browser1 = new FirefoxDriver(driverService);
```